# Is real time communication in matlab possible?

Tags: matlab, real-time, steganography, serial-communication, audio-processing

I am doing audio steganography using dsk TMSC6713. i want to send the message using dsk in real time to a PC, then do all processing and serial communication between the sender and receiver PC in real time using matlab and listen to the sent message at the decoder dsk kit. is it possible?kindly give any possible solutions.

Comment: I mean real time.when i speak from the line in of dsk, i can hear my message at the decoder end. but if real time is not possible,then i will use some quicker alternative which ofcourse wont be real time but response is vital in my project.

Answer (score 0):

in principle it is (almost) impossible to use a consumer PC system for real-time control.

Process scheduling is dependent on so many things that the time to execute a program is non-deterministic. If you want to do real-time anything (communication, control,...) you should go for a micro-controller where you have control over every single cycle and can ensure hard time limits.
If you need, as Mark put it, 'very quick communication', you might be able to do it on a PC (if you're not running Battlefield 2000000 in the background), and maybe even with matlab. It really depends a lot on your needed bandwith. I have done automatic control for RC helicopters at 50Hz using Matlab.

Comment: then is it possble to convert a matlab code directly in C of code composer studio as Iam using DSK TMSC6713?